# How does the Kraus decomposition imply the Stinespring representation?

Tags: quantum-operation, information-theory, unitarity, kraus-representation

To show that the Kraus decomposition $\Phi(\rho)=\sum_{k=1}^D M_k\rho_S M_k^\dagger$ implies the Stinespring form $$\Phi(\rho)=\text{tr}_E[U_{SE}(\rho_S\otimes|0\rangle\langle 0|_E)U_{SE}^\dagger]$$ we first introduce an orthonormal basis $\{|k\rangle_E\}$ for $\mathcal H_E$ and choose a ket $|0\rangle_E$ (for simplicity, this can be done by increasing the dimension of $\mathcal H_E$ to $D+1$ in such a way that $|0\rangle_E$ is actually orthogonal to all $|k\rangle_E$), then we define the operator $U_{SE}$ by the action $$U_{SE}(|\psi\rangle_S\otimes |0\rangle_E)=\sum_{k=1}^D M_k|\psi\rangle_S\otimes |k\rangle_E.$$ Two things are not very clear to me: first, how to go from Kraus to Stinespring using this definition, and secondly how to show that $U_{SE}$ is unitary on all kets in $\mathcal H_{SE}$ when only the action on the hyperplane $|\psi\rangle_S\otimes |0\rangle_E$ is defined. I'd appreciate some pointers as to how to do both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There's no need to increase the dimension of $\newcommand{\calH}{{\mathcal H}}\calH_E$ to $D+1$. All you care about is that $U$ must send orthonormal vectors to orthonormal vectors. What the state $|0\rangle_E$ actually represents is purely conventional. You could put an arbitrary (pure) state there, and get the same channel (as long as you also change the unitary $U$ accordingly, of course).
2. *How to show that $U_{SE}$ is unitary on all kets?* You don't really need to. Or to be more precise, if you want to say that $U_{SE}$ is unitary, then yes, you need to define its action on a full basis of $\calH_{SE}$. But the way it acts on states orthogonal to $|0\rangle_E$ is completely irrelevant from the point of view of the channel $\Phi$, which is, presumably, what you really care about. If for some reason you really want $U_{SE}$ to be unitary, you can pick an arbitrary unitary operator, as long as its action on $|0\rangle_E$ is what it should be.
3. This might be purely conventional, but I wouldn't call the representation you write as the "Stinespring representation". The "Stinespring representation" would be when you write the channel as $\Phi(\rho)=\operatorname{Tr}_E[V\rho V^\dagger]$ for some *isometry* $V:\calH_S\to\calH_{SE}$. Then again, the "unitary representation" (how I would refer to what you are using) and the Stinespring representation are *de facto* equivalent, so this does not matter that much.

   The main advantage of the Stinespring representation with the isometry is that it describes the underlying channel/map in a less redundant way: the freedom in the choice of initial state $|0\rangle_E$ and action of $U_{SE}$ on the auxiliary space disappears when we only write it with $V$.
4. To go from the representation with the unitary to the Kraus operators, a simple way is to decompose in components the various objects, and realise you get a Kraus representation. A starting point would be to write
   $$\operatorname{Tr}_E[U(\rho\otimes |0\rangle\!\langle0|)U^\dagger]
   = \sum_k (I\otimes \langle k|)U(\rho\otimes|0\rangle\!\langle0|)U^\dagger (I\otimes|k\rangle)
   = \sum_k
   \underbrace{(I\otimes \langle k|)U(I\otimes |0\rangle)}_{\equiv A_{k}}
   \rho
   \underbrace{(I\otimes\langle 0|)U^\dagger (I\otimes|k\rangle)}_{= A_k^\dagger}
   \equiv \sum_k A_k \rho A_k^\dagger.$$

   An immediate way to see the relation between Kraus operators and Stinespring isometry $V$, is to notice that $V$, as a matrix, is made up by stacking the operators $A_k$ one on top of the other. Equivalently, the relation between the *unitary* $U_{SE}$ and the Kraus is that $U_{SE}$ is some (any) unitary such that a subset of its columns is built by stacking the Kraus operators $A_k$ one on top of the other. This is the pictorial representation I also mention in [this other answer on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/408976/58382).

   See also:

   - *[Is the Kraus representation of a quantum channel equivalent to a unitary evolution in an enlarged space?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2047/55)*.
   - *[How does $\mathcal E(\rho)=\mathrm{Tr}_{env}[U(\rho\otimes\rho_{env})U^\dagger]$ turn into $P_0\rho P_0+P_1\rho P_1$?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4981/55)*
5. To go from Kraus to Stinespring, reasoning is the same as above. Given $\Phi(X)=\sum_a A_a X A_a^\dagger$ with, note that the linear operator $V\equiv \sum_a (A_a X) \otimes |a\rangle$ is an isometry, if $\sum_a A_a^\dagger A_a = I$, and $\Phi(X)=\operatorname{Tr}_E(V X V^\dagger)$.

Comment: I am confused on the Stinespring point (3). Physicists always write what you've written, but that is *not* the Stinespring theorem, which instead says an CP map $\Phi(\rho)$ can be written as $V^{*} \pi(\rho) V$ where $\pi$ is a $*$-homomorphism from $B(H) \to B(H \otimes K)$ and $V$ is an *isometry* from $H \to H \otimes K$, where $K$ is also a Hilbert space. How do I recover what you've written in (3) from the rigorous math version? Is there a reference that does this? I've been searching for ages.

Comment: @justaphase that's an interesting question, which might be worth asking as a standalone post